# Android Studio - Build variants not showing up

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio to version 0.3.0 and now there are no build variants I can choose from. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, and restarting Android Studio with no success. My build.gradle is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 10
}

productFlavors {
    lite {
        packageName "com.lvl.xpbar"
        versionCode 11
    }

    pro {
        packageName "com.afewguys.raisethebar"
        versionCode 1
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile '/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java','.apt_generated']
        resources.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java','.apt_generated']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java','.apt_generated']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['/src/main/java','.apt_generated']
        res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    lite {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    pro {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your /gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties file update the following setting to:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

Now, go to Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

This will download the latest distribution of Gradle and automatically reload your project and build variants after it's finished.

Make sure to update your project's build.gradle files to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
```

Comment: I even can't find the Tools->Android menu. My project is an android library. (I can compile and run within another project without problem.)

Comment: I think Build Variants have been removed from Android Studio but they forgot to update the documentation.

Comment: Nothing was removed. They only changed the menu - Android Studio 3.6.1: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 45):

You need to sync project with Gradle files:

In current versions of Android Studio: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

In old versions (pre 3.0): Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Doesn't exist:  File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: I can see it using Android Studio 3.5.2 in linux. Which version and OS are you using?

Comment: thanks!, this answer works in 'Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1' also

Comment: macOS does not have this option under File