# Android Studio toolbar, some parts missing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Build variants, Commander, Change, etc. are missing in my Android Studio.
See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

How can i bring these up?

Comment: [Here is an answer for the Build variants missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480538/android-studio-build-variants-not-showing-up) You can try it if you have updated your Android Studio recently

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?