# Build Variants not showing on Android Studio Cordova Project

Tags: android, cordova

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 and Android Studio 2.3.3.
I've developed a web application and made a Cordova project from it.
Now I've created android platform, and need to open the platform with Android Studio in order to sign the app and upload it to the Play Store.

The thing is that Build Variants option is not showing. Don't know what I'm missing.

I checked this link

[Android Studio - Build variants not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480538/android-studio-build-variants-not-showing-up)

But no results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Of course it won't show as an Android module, the project is generated very differently. You can [sign the app manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930331/how-to-sign-an-already-compiled-apk)

Comment: I just downloaded the repo on my office mac, and Build Variants shows on it. But not on Linux. Any idea why might it be?

Comment: No. Good to know it shows on a Mac though

Comment: I have remove the Android Studio tag. The tag is only for questions about the IDE itself, not about projects in the IDE